# Prestashop prevent impossible combination selection

Tags: javascript, prestashop

I'm setting up a shop ATM and I have product which can have multiple combinations.
However, some combinations are not possible.
If I choose a combination that is not possible, a message appears saying that the product does not exist in this combination.

I would like to prevent the user from selecting that combination in the first place.
I can think of something like disabling/hiding the dropdown selectors.

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

you can play in the combinations ID. Check the product.tpl and you get the list,you can go with an if/else to disable some combinations ID

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways:

1. using third-party modules like [these](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/141224-unavailable-product-attributes-on-product-page/#entry726349)
2. rewrite function `updateDisplay()` in **themes/yourtheme/js/product.js**. There is a code for showing messages when product attribute (combination) is out of stock or does not exists.